# write lsmeans into a function with "%>%"

Tags: r, function, rlang, lsmeans

Using "mpg" data as an example, 
I wrote some code to call lsmeans function in the non-function format, and the output is good to me (as shown below).

I try to modify the codes into a function format to generate the same output, but the columns of the data could not be recognized in the function I wrote.

Errors reported from my function is:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'cty' not found
```

## My codes not in the function format that work fine:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(multcompView)
library(lsmeans)


model = lm(cty ~ drv + class + drv:class,data=mpg)
anova(model)

marginal = lsmeans(model,~drv:class)

Pletters = multcomp::cld(marginal,
          alpha=0.05,
          Letters=letters,
          adjust="tukey")
Pletters$.group=gsub(" ", "", Pletters$.group)
Pletters
```

## Function code I wrote that did not work for me:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(multcompView)
library(lsmeans)

P_letters<-function(data, y, groupby, subgroupby){

model = lm(y ~ groupby + subgroupby + groupby:subgroupby,data=data)
anova(model)

marginal = lsmeans(model,~groupby:subgroupby)

Pletters = multcomp::cld(marginal,
          alpha=0.05,
          Letters=letters,
          adjust="tukey")
Pletters$.group=gsub(" ", "", Pletters$.group)
Pletters
}
```

## Call the function with "mpg" data:

```
result<-mpg %>%  
P_letters(y=cty, groupby=drv, subgroupby=class)
result
```

## Output from the non-function format codes:

```
nalysis of Variance Table

Response: cty
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
drv         2 1878.81  939.41 136.6198 <2e-16 ***
class       6  804.78  134.13  19.5069 <2e-16 ***
drv:class   3   10.26    3.42   0.4974 0.6844    
Residuals 222 1526.49    6.88                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 drv class      lsmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 r   suv          12.0 0.791 222     9.58     14.4 a     
 4   pickup       13.0 0.456 222    11.60     14.4 a     
 4   suv          13.8 0.367 222    12.70     14.9 a     
 r   2seater      15.4 1.173 222    11.80     19.0 ab    
 f   minivan      15.8 0.791 222    13.39     18.2 ab    
 r   subcompact   15.9 0.874 222    13.21     18.6 ab    
 4   midsize      16.0 1.514 222    11.36     20.6 abc   
 4   compact      18.0 0.757 222    15.68     20.3 bc    
 f   midsize      19.0 0.425 222    17.67     20.3 bc    
 4   subcompact   19.5 1.311 222    15.48     23.5 bcd   
 f   compact      20.9 0.443 222    19.50     22.2 cd    
 f   subcompact   22.4 0.559 222    20.65     24.1 d     
 4   2seater    nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 f   2seater    nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 r   compact    nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 r   midsize    nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 4   minivan    nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 r   minivan    nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 f   pickup     nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 r   pickup     nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       
 f   suv        nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA       

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 21 estimates 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 21 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05
```

## Error from my function format code:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'cty' not found
```

Comment: You need to construct the formula from a string. Try `as.formula("y ~ groupby + subgroupby + groupby:subgroupby")` and the same goes for the interaction in `lsmeans`.

Comment: Hi, Roman Do you mean change the code as this? If so, it still results in the same error. Maybe i did not understand you correctly. Appreciate for further clarification.   
`model = lm(as.formula("y ~ groupby + subgroupby + groupby:subgroupby"),data=data)
anova(model)
marginal = lsmeans(as.formula("model,~groupby:subgroupby"))`

Comment: Or this does not work either: `model = lm(as.formula("y ~ groupby + subgroupby + groupby:subgroupby"),data=data)
anova(model)

marginal = lsmeans(model,as.formula("~groupby:subgroupby"))`

Comment: Lapsus, you need to paste together the formula, e.g. using `paste` or as I did, `sprintf`: `var1 <- "groupby";
var2 <- "subgroupby";
dep <- "y";
as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s + %s + %s:%s", dep, var1, var2, var1, var2))`

Comment: `P_letters<-function(mydata, y, groupby, subgroupby){
        var1 <- "groupby"
        var2 <- "subgroupby" 
        dep <- "y"
        model = lm(as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s + %s + %s:%s", dep, var1, var2, var1, var2)),data=mydata)
anova(model)

marginal = lsmeans (as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s:%s", model, var1, var2)))

Pletters = multcomp::cld(marginal,
           alpha=0.05,
           Letters=letters,
           adjust="tukey")
Pletters$.group=gsub(" ", "", Pletters$.group)
Pletters
}`

Comment: Hi, Roman Above is how I modified my code according to your suggestion, based on my best knowledge. I am so new to R, must misunderstand or made something wrong, as this modified code still does not work. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some R functions operate directly on the expressions that a user writes, instead of evaluating them. It's a fairly advanced concept known as non-standard evaluation (NSE), and you can learn more about it in the recent [tidy evaluation guide](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/). As a very brief example of NSE, consider the `library()` function:

```
library("tidyverse")              # Works

a <- "tidyverse"
library( a )
# Error in library(a) : there is no package called ‘a’
```

If `library()` used standard evaluation rules, the expression `a` would have been evaluated to produce the value `"tidyverse"`, which would then be passed to `library()`. However, because of NSE, the function works directly with `a`, instead of evaluating it.

The functions you are trying to use fall under the same umbrella and require special treatment to handle user-supplied expressions. The `rlang` package provides [several mechanisms for this](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html). In particular, we will use 1) `ensym()` to capture the variable name supplied to the function; 2) `expr()` to compose an unevaluated expression; 3) `!!` operator to force expression evaluation.

```
P_letters <- function(data, y, groupby, subgroupby) {
  ## Compose a formula expression using user-supplied variable names
  frml <- expr( !!ensym(y) ~ !!ensym(groupby) + !!ensym(subgroupby) +
                    !!ensym(groupby):!!ensym(subgroupby) )

  ## Pass the formula expression to lm()
  model <- lm(frml,data=data)
  print(anova(model))

  ## Compose and evaluate an expression for lsmean() call
  lsm_expr <- expr( lsmeans(model,~!!ensym(groupby):!!ensym(subgroupby)) )
  marginal <- eval(lsm_expr)

  Pletters <- multcomp::cld(marginal, alpha=0.05,
                          Letters=letters, adjust="tukey")
  Pletters$.group=gsub(" ", "", Pletters$.group)
  Pletters
}

## This now produces the desired output
mpg %>% P_letters( y=cty, groupby=drv, subgroupby=class )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Artem! It is greatly helpful! I will read the rlang manual, it seems will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Hi, Artem, I am trying to pass some data in "Pletters" to another function, but realize when I was calling "Pletters", it cannot be found, reported as "Error: object 'Pletters' not found".

Comment: @Meadowstrain: `Pletters` is a local variable; it is not visible outside the function where it is defined. However, because it is returned by the function, you can simply assign the output of the function to another variable: `myvar <- mpg %>% P_letters( y=cty, groupby=drv, subgroup=class)`.

Comment: Got it! 
Thank you so much Artem!

Comment: You're welcome, @Meadowstrain. Consider accepting this answer (by clicking the green checkmark), so the question would no longer appear in the "Unanswered" category.